# How to do I send validation messages form model to view in the MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I've got a small test WPF MVVM application working in which a view allows the user to change the first or last names of customers and the full name automatically changes, so communication is going from M-to-MV-to-V and back, everything is fully decoupled, so far so good.

But now as I look to how I will begin extending this to build large applications with the MVVM pattern, I find the decoupling to be an obstacle, namely:

- **how will I do validation messages**, e.g. if back in the model in the LastName setter I add code that prevents names over 50 characters from being set, **how can I send a messsage to the view** telling it to display a message that the name was too long?
- in complex applications **I may have dozens of views on a screen** at one time, yet I understand that in MVVM each view has one and only one ViewModel assigned to it to provide it with data and behavior, so **how is it that the views can interact with each other**, e.g. in the above validation example, what if back in the customer model we want to inform a particular "MessageAreaView" to display the message "Last name may only contain 50 characters.", how to we communicate that up the stack to that particular view?

**CustomerHeaderView.xaml (View):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMvvm444.Views.CustomerHeaderView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBox
                                Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                Width="100" 
                                Margin="3 5 3 5"/>
                                <TextBox 
                                Text="{Binding Path=LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                Width="100"
                                Margin="0 5 3 5"/>
                                <TextBlock 
                                Text="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                Margin="0 5 3 5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Customer.cs (Model):**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestMvvm444.Model
{
    class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfContracts { get; set; }

        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set
            {
                if (firstName != value)
                {
                    firstName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");

                }
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set
            {
                if (lastName != value)
                {
                    lastName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return firstName + " " + lastName; }
        }



        #region PropertChanged Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple way to add validation messages is to use binding.

Add an notifable property to your view model that defines whether the validation message should be displayed or not:

```
private Boolean _itemValidatorDisplayed;
public Boolean ItemValidatorDisplayed
{
    get { return _itemValidatorDisplayed; }
    set
    {
        _itemValidatorDisplayed= value;
        _OnPropertyChanged("ItemValidatorDisplayed");
    }
}
```

Add a convertor class that converts bool to visibility:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace xxx
{
    public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public bool Negate { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool val = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            if (!Negate)
            {
                return val ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                return val ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Bind to the property from the view and apply the converter:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="ViewClass"
    ...
    >
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <contract:BoolToVisibilityConverter Negate="False"
                                                x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        </UserControl.Resources>

...

<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Path=ItemValidatorDisplayed}" />

...

</UserControl>
```

You'll need to be setting the ViewModel as the datacontext of the view:

```
namespace xxx
{
    public partial class ViewClass: UserControl
    {
        public ViewClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new ViewClass_ViewModel();
        }
}
}
```

Bingo - perfectly working validation being pushed to any view that cares to subscribe to this ViewModel / Property.

Answer (score 6):

For validation, have your view model implement [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx). As for communication between views, don't be afraid to write UI services (eg. a message service that allows and view model to contribute messages that will be displayed somewhere in the UI). Or if there is a hard relationship between view models (eg. one view model owns another) then the owning view model can hold a reference to the child view model.

Answer (score 0):

You will also be able to bind validation to the source object collection in SL3 :-)